# What‘s the diameter of the engines of the Airbus E-Fan?

Tags: aircraft-design, jet-engine, airbus, electric-engine, airplane

does somebody know the diameter of the E-Fan‘s engines ? 
To me the look like around 80cm or what do you think ? 
Also, with more and wider blades and 60 kW motors instead of 30 couldn‘t they get much more thrust out of them than 75 kg ?

Thanks for your answers!

Simon

Comment: Please be aware that you are asking two different questions, and that the second is not represented in your title, meaning that people will come to read your question to answer the first, not the second.